# Could not find the resource among the resources embedded in the assembly

Tags: c#, .net, azure-pipelines

I have two resource files AppMessage.en.resx and AppMessage.pt-BR.resx. I also have a Designer file named AppMessage.en.Designer.cs.

This is my Designer file:

```
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder", "17.0.0.0")]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
    public class AppMessage {
        
        private static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager resourceMan;
        
        private static global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo resourceCulture;
        
        [global::System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1811:AvoidUncalledPrivateCode")]
        internal AppMessage() {
        }
        
        /// <summary>
        ///   Returns the cached ResourceManager instance used by this class.
        /// </summary>
        [global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
        public static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager {
            get {
                if (object.ReferenceEquals(resourceMan, null)) {
                    global::System.Resources.ResourceManager temp = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("Ultrasonic.Customers.Application.Resources.AppMessage", typeof(AppMessage).Assembly);
                    resourceMan = temp;
                }
                return resourceMan;
            }
        }
        
        /// <summary>
        ///   Overrides the current thread's CurrentUICulture property for all
        ///   resource lookups using this strongly typed resource class.
        /// </summary>
        [global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
        public static global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo Culture {
            get {
                return resourceCulture;
            }
            set {
                resourceCulture = value;
            }
        }
        
        /// <summary>
        ///   Looks up a localized string similar to Employee must be 15 years of age or older..
        /// </summary>
        public static string Validation_BirthDate {
            get {
                return ResourceManager.GetString("Validation.BirthDate", resourceCulture);
            }
        }
        
        /// <summary>
        ///   Looks up a localized string similar to {PropertyName} Must be a valid date, greater or equals tomorrow.
        /// </summary>
        public static string Validation_CreditDate {
            get {
                return ResourceManager.GetString("Validation.CreditDate", resourceCulture);
            }
        }
        
        /// <summary>
        ///   Looks up a localized string similar to {PropertyName} cannot be null.
        /// </summary>
        public static string Validation_NullCheck {
            get {
                return ResourceManager.GetString("Validation.NullCheck", resourceCulture);
            }
        }
        
        /// <summary>
        ///   Looks up a localized string similar to {PropertyName} Invalid Date.
        /// </summary>
        public static string Validation_ValidDate {
            get {
                return ResourceManager.GetString("Validation.ValidDate", resourceCulture);
            }
        }
        
        /// <summary>
        ///   Looks up a localized string similar to {PropertyName} only digits allowed, must be 8 caracters lenth.
        /// </summary>
        public static string Validation_ZipCode {
            get {
                return ResourceManager.GetString("Validation.ZipCode", resourceCulture);
            }
        }
    }
```

I noticed that in the azure pipeline it gives the error due to this line:

```
global::System.Resources.ResourceManager temp = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("Ultrasonic.Customers.Application.Resources.AppMessage", typeof(AppMessage).Assembly);
```

Locally when i change it to:

```
"Ultrasonic.Customers.Application.Resources.AppMessage.en"
```

with the "en" on the final, i can reproduce the error:

```
Message: 
    System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException : Could not find the resource "Ultrasonic.Customers.Application.Resources.AppMessage.en.resources" among the resources "" embedded in the assembly "Ultrasonic.Customers.Application", nor among the resources in any satellite assemblies for the specified culture. Perhaps the resources were embedded with an incorrect name.
```

And when i change it back to:

```
"Ultrasonic.Customers.Application.Resources.AppMessage"
```

*locally* seems resolved. But in Azure pipelines, it keeps complaining about not finding it. My question is, what should I put here so it can be correct? Thanks in advance.

Here are the properties:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone is going through this, just leave a neutral file, with a Designer. this solves the problem.

Basically I deleted the AppMessage.en.resx and created an AppMessage.resx.

Comment: For me there was just a missing .resx file for one of the forms.